# backtracking in python // efficiency + memory layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, backtracking

is there any difference between the following two implementations of backtracking in Python in terms of efficiency and memory layout:

```
class Solution:
    def allPathsSourceTarget(self, graph: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        if not graph:
            return  []
        
        def find_paths(node, path):
            if node == target:
                paths.append(path)
                return
            
            for x in graph[node]:
                find_paths(x, path + [x])
            
        
        paths = []
        source = 0
        target = len(graph) - 1
        
        find_paths(source, [source])
        
        return paths
```

and

```
class Solution:
    def allPathsSourceTarget(self, graph: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        if not graph:
            return  []
        
        def find_paths(node, path):
            if node == target:
                paths.append(list(path))
                return
            
            for x in graph[node]:
                path.append(x)
                find_paths(x, path)
                path.pop()
            
        
        paths = []
        source = 0
        target = len(graph) - 1
        
        find_paths(source, [source])
        
        return paths
```

the second version seems to be slightly quicker on the Leetcode web page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you timed these yourself? the leetcode timer is not really accurate back when I used to frequent it

Comment: nope I have not so far, a good point